# hashbang vs hijax

Tags: javascript, seo

Can anyone give me a good reason why not to use the hijax (Progressive enhancement) method in addition to the hashbang method google proposes? As far as i can see, the hijax method is still the better one:

- it works for no-javascript browsers
- all search engines can index

The only counter argument i found so far is when they click on a link in a search engine and you have javascript enabled you'll need to do a redirect to the javascript enabled version (with the #-tag).

For Google's hashbang version it's difficult to supply a no-javascript based version and Bing and Yahoo can't crawl your website.

Kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 6):

The "value allocation" answer isn't quite correct.

The question is regarding surfacing content *for search engines*. Hashbang is Google's answer for that. That said, a user (or another search engine or social network scraper that doesn't support hashbang) who doesn't have JS enabled will never see your content. Google can see it because they're the one's checking for hashbang.

Hijax, on the other hand, always allows non-JS users/bots to see your content because it does *not* rely on hash/hashbang. Hijax relies on standard query string parameters. This means your application must have back-end logic to render your content for non-JS user agents. In the end, with Hijax JS enabled users get the asynchronous experience and non-JS enabled users get full page loads.

Google continues to recommend Hijax. Hashbang is their offering for non-hijax apps already out there in the wild, and/or JS apps that don't have a back-end.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html
(see progressive enhancement section)

Comment: Very well put... I also came up with an identical answer searching the web and I think that the Hijax approach is better ie. more general then googles hashbang.

Comment: Since I can't comment on the posts below, I hope everyone has done their reading on how awful the hashbang is and how jumping on the latest at-first-glance neato thing isn't really a wise idea:

<http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch>
(A Google employee no less)

<http://blog.benward.me/post/3231388630>

<http://www.netmagazine.com/news/twitter-hashbang-walloped-121992>

Answer (score 5):

The reason is value allocation

### Hijax

1. Ok lets say a user links to `http://www.example.com/stuff#fluff`
2. The link actually counts as a link to `http://www.example.com/stuff#fluff` but as 
   `http://www.example.com/stuff#fluff` and `http://www.example.com/stuff` are the same HTML content, google will canonicalize (summarize) the value allocation to `http://www.example.com/stuff`
3. Your site www.example.com/stuff/fluff that you communicated to non javascript clients (googlebot) does not come up in this whole process

**Fazit:** so basically a link to `http://www.example.com/stuff#fluff` is seen by google as a vote for `http://www.example.com/stuff`

### Hashbang

1. A user links to `http://www.example.com/stuff#!fluff`
2. Googlebot interpretes it as `www.example.com/stuff?_escaped_fragment_=fluff`
3. And as it offers different content (i.e.: different content from `www.example.com/stuff`) google will not canonicalize (summerize) it with any other URL.
4. Google will display `http://www.example.com/stuff#!fluff` to it's users

**Fazit:** A link to `http://www.example.com/stuff#!fluff` is seen by google as a vote for `www.example.com/stuff?_escaped_fragment_=fluff` (but displayed to it's users as `http://www.example.com/stuff#!fluff`)

Comment: In your Hijax example to make thing clear your 1st point is about a user sharing / bookmarking the URL which contains the #. When they link back to your site with the # url Google only allocates value to /stuff... This is true; unless you provide a way for users to share the /stuff/fluff urls - but in that case you do need to do a javascript redirect to /stuff#fluff. I'm not sure tho if Google marks this process as "Sneaky JavaScript redirects" - http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355. You did however present a good reason. +1

Comment: Re: point #2 on hijax -- using the HTML5 history API's pushState() you can mitigate this issue in supporting browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=history); the link in the address bar can be made to look as if it was accessed at the "hijaxed" URL).  Not a 100% satisfactory solution but on many sites it would cover the majority of users.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is not an issue any more, since Bing (this means Yahoo as well) started crawling ajax pages employing google's hashbang proposal!

[Lense about ajax-crawling in Bing](http://www.squidoo.com/ajax-crawling)

Answer (score 1):

Use dual links (AJAX and normal links), they are compatible with Bing, Yahoo and others

Take a look to [Single Page Interface and Search Engine Optimization](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/php/spim/spi_manifesto_en.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example http://www.amitpatil.me/create-gmail-like-app-using-html5-history-api-and-hashbang/